# Updating client image after interval when server sends new image

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, signalr

In my ASP.NET MVC application, server is broadcasting image URL to all clients after 5 seconds
I am using SignalR to send image URL from server which invokes Javascript function.

In the Javascript function I am using following code to auto-refresh `<img>` element to update the `src` attribute but though it is updating my src I am not able to see on browser.

```
// Defining a connection to the server hub.
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
// Setting logging to true so that we can see whats happening in the browser console log. [OPTIONAL]
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
// Start the hub
$.connection.hub.start();

// This is the client method which is being called inside the MyHub constructor method every 3 seconds

myHub.client.SendServerImageUrl = function (serverImageUrl) {
var N = 5;
// Function that refreshes image
function refresh(imageId, imageSrc) {
    var image = document.getElementById(imageId);
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    image.src = imageSrc + '?' + timestamp;
};
// Refresh image every N seconds
setTimeout(function () {
    refresh('SampleImage', serverImageUrl);
}, N * 1000);
```

My HTML file contains only following code:

```
<img id="SampleImage">
```

Backend C# code

```
 public class MyHub : Hub
     {
         public MyHub()
         {
         // Create a Long running task to do an infinite loop which will keep sending the server time
        // to the clients every 5 seconds.
        var taskTimer = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while(true)
                {

                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    int number = rnd.Next(1,10);
                    string str = "~/Images/Sample";


                    Clients.All.SendServerImageUrl(str+Convert.ToString(number)+".jpg");

                    //Delaying by 5 seconds.
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery? Try changing your HTML to `<img id="SampleImage" src="" />`.

Comment: Where is your `$.connection` callback being registered?

Comment: @DevlshOne Thank you for editing.
I tried your suggestions. 
after 5 seconds it is updating src attribute but it is not showing image on browser 
Please help thank you

Comment: @Rohit thank you can you post your backend C# code?

Comment: @beautifulcoder updated with backend c#.. Sorry for trouble.
Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the casing in your callbacks:

```
myHub.client.sendServerImageUrl = ...;

Clients.All.sendServerImageUrl(...);
```

There should be no need for polling so get rid of `setTimeout()` on the client.

Keep an eye on the Console and make sure HTTP requests are working.

Comment: Hello I don't think that's the problem because server is sending url for example "`/images/1.jpg " correctly.But client is not displaying that image. I can see img tag getting updated with new src attribute but it does not show images.